# How to combine two arrays like this?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

**$blueswards array:**

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 8 [2] => 1 [3] => 4 [4] => 9 )
```

**$redswards array:**

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 9 [2] => 3 [3] => 6 [4] => 9 )
```

What i try to do:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 8 [2] => 1 [3] => 4 [4] => 9 [5] => 2 [6] => 9 [7] => 3 [8] => 6 [9] => 9 )
```

I cant do it with `array_merge`.

EDIT = Sorry everyone i did it with array merge now its working. :[

Comment: What's wrong with using `array_merge()`?

Comment: Show your code which you tried using `array_merge()`

Comment: If you ask for a way to use a nail but we can't use the hammer, you should at least probably explain why we need to try to make it work with a screwdriver.

Comment: @yusuf-devranlı really, i'm very curious to know why you can use `array_merge`... please tell us...

Comment: Sorry my bad. array_merge is working sorry.

Comment: Hi @YusufDevranlı: I am eager to know what mistake you did.

Comment: @NanaPartykar i saw http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php first example in this link and thought it wouldnt work. also my brain stopped working im dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `array_merge()` using your array values. And, it worked.

```
<?php

$new_array[] = array(); 

$blueswards = array(3,8,4,9);
$redswards = array(2,9,3,6,9);

$new_array = array_merge($blueswards,$redswards);

print_r($new_array);

?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 8 [2] => 4 [3] => 9 [4] => 2 [5] => 9 [6] => 3 [7] => 6 [8] => 9 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run them in a loop once they're populated.

```
$newarray=0;
$arrayCounter=0;
for (i=0; i<count($redswards)-1 ; i++){
    $newarray[$arrayCounter] = $redswards[i];
    $arrayCounter++
}
for (i=0; i<count($blueswards)-1 ; i++){
    $newarray[$arrayCounter] = $blueswards[i];
    $arrayCounter++
}
```

There...  That will do it correctly by simply adding on to the new array.  It will also count the number of times it has to loop so you don't have to hardcode that.

I mean, that's really simple, and you may have to change the hardcoded i values.  But that's the basic idea.

Comment: Are you sure that will work? In my opinion you need two variables to keep track of the two arrays. In the second loop you start i at 5. And blueswards only have 4 values. You need i and j counters.

Comment: Eh...  Lemme do a better version...  (correcting answer)

Answer (score 0):

Used durbnpolsns code and edited it to work.

```
$newarray=0;
for ($i=0; $i<4 ; $i++){
    $newarray[$i] = $redswards[$i];
}
$j=0;
for ($i=5; $i<8 ; $i++){
    $newarray[$i] = $blueswards[$j];
    $j++;
}
```

I have not tested the code and formatting may be impossible, but I'm typing on my phone.
Sorry for that.